# Finished Loading of ng-include in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the best way to detect the end of html loading by `ng–include`? I want to write some code that runs when it has finished loading.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There are two ways to detect when `ng-include` finished loading, depending on your need:

1) via [`onload`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude#usage) attribute - for inline expressions. Ex:

```
<div ng-include="'template.html'" onload="loaded = true"></div>
```

2) via an event [`$includeContentLoaded`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude#$includeContentLoaded) that `ng-include` emits - for app-wide handling. Ex:

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.$on("$includeContentLoaded", function(event, templateName){
     //...
  });
});
```

when it finishes loading the content

Comment: NOTE: there is a major difference between these two sections of code. The `onload` attribute will be called AFTER all images and content within the template is loaded, whereas `$includeContentLoaded` will load BEFORE any images are loaded; it will load when the arbitrary HTML content is loaded into the `<div>`.

Comment: @think123 it seems to me that both events are fired at the same time? [check the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7717de4c51fcb8018a2b5fecc6c1300bb6e1c2c0/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L257)

Answer (score 16):

you can use `onload` for it as below

```
<div ng-include=".." onload="finishLoading()"></div>
```

in controller,

```
$scope.finishLoading = function() {

}
```

after loading the `ng-include` `finishLoading` scope function will call.

here is the working [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYAZ8RFWQWeAEr2Ug9qg?p=preview)

Answer (score 8):

You can use this code:

```
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
    // it has loaded!
});
```

Comment: How this answer add anything new?

Comment: The best clean and fastest angular way response here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example that will catch all the `ng-include` load events emitted by the application:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-include="'snippet.html'"></div>
    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
      myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event, target){
          console.log(event);  //this $includeContentLoaded event object
          console.log(target); //path to the included resource, 'snippet.html' in this case
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A problem I had, and the reason I take the time to post this, is I failed to include both the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in my HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to wait for the element to be present, I wrap a `$timeout` with `$includeContentLoaded`:

```
var selector = '#foo';
$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event, templateName){
  $timeout(() => {
    const $el = angular.element(selector);
    if ($el.length) {
      // Do stuff with element.
    }
  });
});
```

The timeout gives it time load properly, specially if the `ng-include` contains a directive that takes a few milliseconds to render.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative for that only using JS call stack tricks. put `ng-init="eventName"` on the desired element. After that, declare the event on the angular controller:

```
$scope.eventName = () => {
  setTimeout(() => { alert('loaded!'); }, 0);
}
```

That makes the alert only pop up when everything about angular is loaded, that occur because of the call-stack of JavaScript that considers some codes as Microtasks and some others as Macrotasks and they have priorities like the Microtasks run always first and just after all Microtasks run, the Macrotasks can take the place on the call-stack.

And, `setTimeout()` is considered a Macrotask for JavaScript, so it will only run as the latest tasks.