# Access DOM element within ng-include partial from angular service

Tags: angularjs

Markup for splash.html:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

I've defined my view in the controller with:

```
$scope.splashView = "partials/splash.html";
```

My module looks like:

```
angular.module('splash', [])
    .service("splashLoader", ['$document', function ($document) {

        var document = $document[0];
        var adv = document.getElementById('test');
        console.log(adv); // is null

}]);
```

The partial renders fine, but I get a null value when I attempt to access the element from with the service. How can I access the test element with javascript or using an angular method? I'm guessing that it has to do with scope, but I'm a bit lost.

Thanks

Comment: this is really backwards thinking in angular ... the data model should dictate what is available in dom and services run before controller or template is loaded

Comment: Where do you suggest I place this logic?

Comment: what are you trying to do? If you need to manipulate the dom also....you would use a directive and any code in directive will only run when element exists

Comment: My first goal is to unclutter index.html by putting markup in the partial. Second, I'd like to put all of my code for handling a loading animation in a module/service or something similar. I'm trying to access the element to trigger an animation timeline.

Comment: are you using a router?...that's easiest way to split up views

Comment: I'm building a single page app. I was thinking of using splash.html as a snippet of html that would fade out using opacity. I'm routing the other sections of the site.

Comment: fine but you use an angular router in single page app to navigate between views. Really sounds like you should go through tutorial on documentation site and get a better grasp of how angular works and what it can do

Comment: Perhaps I'm using ng-include incorrectly. I was essentially just trying to add some markup that I could easily manipulate. I never intended to programmatically hide or navigate with that bit of HTML. All of my other partials are arranged using angular router, as you said.Thanks

Comment: ok..that's fine...can use a dynamic ng-include if that's all you need also. But your data model would determine what is being presented and you can use directives to manipulate the dom

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was attempting to access the element without it being ready in DOM. I will definitely apply the tips provided by @charlietfl, especially using directives for additional DOM manipulation.

This answer below, describes a couple techniques for ensuring that ng-include has loaded.

[Finished Loading of ng-include in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576643/finished-loading-of-ng-include-in-angular-js)