# jQuery nth-child() inserting css class in the second li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want insert the class `.tech` in the second `<li>` what it is wrong in that code bellow?

**html:**

```
<div class="menu">
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <div class="client">
      <div class="client-open">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li>link1</li>
          <li>link 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sidebar-nav ul li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass('tech');
});
```

Comment: There's no `ul` inside `.sidebar-nav`. `$("ul.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2)")`

Answer (score 1):

`.sidebar-nav` is the ul so no need for `ul` in selector after `.sidebar-nav` :

```
$( ".sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass('tech');
```

You could add it before the class to specify that the class belong to `ul` :

```
$( "ul.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass('tech');
```

**NOTE :** Since you're using jquery you could use **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** (zero-based) selector instead :

```
$( "ul.sidebar-nav li:eq(1)" ).addClass('tech');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  $( "ul.sidebar-nav li:eq(1)" ).addClass('tech');
});
```

```css
.tech{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <div class="client">
      <div class="client-open">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li>link1</li>
          <li>link 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: its very strange what it is happening, if I insert the code in the html does not work, but if insert on my console, it is works, any idea what is happening? thanks

Comment: Not sure, it works in my side locally. just make sure is there any error in the console and make sure the code wrapped in ready function...

Comment: i found the error but not how to fix, the problem is because i am using:  <nav class="sidebar"><div ng-include="'app/client.html'"></div></nav> , i tried put the js into de file client.html, but still did not work, how can i solve this? thanks

Comment: I'm not an angular developer sorry :( but I think this link should helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576643/finished-loading-of-ng-include-in-angular-js.

Answer (score 1):

1. change `.sidebar-nav ul` to `.sidebar-nav` because class `.sidebar-nav` is already the `ul` what your code does is it searches a ul inside your class `.sidebar-nav` which is one and the same that is why you are not adding the class

You can update your selector to:

```
$(".sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2)").addClass('tech');
// or
$("ul.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2)").addClass('tech');
```

```js
$(".sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2)").addClass('tech');
```

```css
.tech {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <div class="client">
      <div class="client-open">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li>link1</li>
          <li>link 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed. Just putting working code is not a good answer

Comment: @Rajesh he posted without explanation because of getting votes

Comment: @guradio Please check my update and revert it if not required

Comment: its very strange what it is happening, if I insert the code in the html does not work, but if insert on my console, it is works, any idea what is happening? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$(function() {
 $( "ul.sidebar-nav li:eq(1)").addClass('tech');
});
```