# ngInclude - how pass the target element to its onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onload, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to pass the trigerring element of the ng-include to its onload method like this:

```
<ng-include src="'/User/EditIcon.html'" onload="finished(this)"></ng-include>
```

And in the ctrl:

```
$scope.finished = function(elem){...}
```

When I pass "this" it references the scope itself.
When I pass $event or event - they are undefined.

I'm familiar with $includeContentLoaded but I prefer to not use it.
I've been googling and SOFing with no success

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576643/finished-loading-of-ng-include-in-angular-js

Comment: Thanks, I saw it when I was looking for an event which is being fired once the ngInclude directive is finished with loading its content, but they don't tell anything about passing the target element to the onload event though.

Comment: did you try passing `$event` instead of `this` from view?

Comment: Yeap, as I mentioned "When I pass $event or event - they are undefined". I meant when I pass in the view $event or event, then in the scope's method, that parameter ($event or event) is undefined.